# trouble installing Wordpress on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I'm brand new to Ubuntu. Goes from Windows 10 and will in the future be Ubuntu Linux man. I'm having trouble installing Wordpress on my localhost. Localhost runs on Apache2 and works fine so I can open the index. php and index.html from htdocs. How do I most easily install Wordpress on my localhoost?

Answer (score 0):

```
root@buster-raspi:~# apt-cache search wordpress
libmarkdown-php - PHP library for rendering Markdown data
elpa-php-mode - PHP Mode for GNU Emacs
qtm - Web-log interface program
ruby-omniauth-wordpress - Wordpress strategy for OmniAuth
wordpress - weblog manager
wordpress-l10n - weblog manager - language files
wordpress-theme-twentynineteen - weblog manager - twentynineteen theme files
wordpress-theme-twentyseventeen - weblog manager - twentyseventeen theme files
wordpress-theme-twentysixteen - weblog manager - twentysixteen theme files
wordpress-shibboleth - Shibboleth plugin for WordPress
wordpress-xrds-simple - XRDS-Simple plugin for WordPress
```

So an `apt install wordpress` will do it on Debian, Ubuntu does not change the names much so should be the same.